# Migrating key to new table

Tags: sql

I have a table with a key relating to a different table which I need to change to point to a different table.

**Table A** is the table being edited I am moving the Id to point from **Table B Old** to **Table B New**.

I cannot edit the schema of the existing tables.

**Table A before** (cannot edit schema)

```
Unique_Id  TableB_Id
1          10
2          11
3          11
4          12
```

**Table A after**

```
Unique_Id  TableB_Id
1          12
2          13
3          13
4          13
```

Where I have (albeit in a spreadsheet at the moment) this **mapping**

```
Old_Id     New_Id
10         12
11         13
12         13
```

Obviously I can't go through and individually replace `10` with `12`, `11` with `13`, `12` with `13` because then the `TableB_Id` column will read `13, 13, 13, 13`.

Hopefully that makes sense. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table called `Mapping` with the contents of your spreadsheet.

```
UPDATE  a
SET     TableB_Id = m.New_Id
FROM    TableA a
        INNER JOIN
                Mapping m
                ON a.TableB_Id = m.Old_ID
```

Comment: Apologies I made a small error in my question - should have read **Table A before** and **Table A after**. **Table B** being another table

Comment: I've added clarification.

Comment: On a side note, what will this do if `TableB_Id` doesn't have a equivalent in `Mapping`? Will it strip out that record from `TableA`?

Comment: To answer my own question, yes. In order to not do this I would have to do a `LEFT JOIN`, yes?

Comment: It won't strip it out, but it won't be modified. If yu do this as a `LEFT JOIN`, then non-matched rows would have their TableB_Id values set to `NULL` instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Obviously I can't go through and individually replace 10 with 12, 11
>   with 13, 12 with 13 because then the TableB_Id column will read 13,
>   13, 13, 13

Why not? If you only update by Unique_ID, it will only update 1 row at a time.

Wouldn't this work:

```
-- Iterate over each row in excel file
Update TableA
Set TableB_Id = New_ID
Where Unique_ID = [new field to add to excel table corresponding to the unique_id]
```

Comment: Are you suggesting looping through by `Unique_Id`?

Comment: I don't see how your code example stops the problem I stated from occuring...?

Comment: Because you're updating the "10" to "12" only when Unique_ID = 1, Then go to the next Unique_ID and update that value...

Comment: Ah, did you mean `-- Iterate over each row in Table A` then?